# Cloning Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, backup, cloning

I want to download and run a PROD DB on my local env. Are there any easy Gui Tools I can use to do this?

I would rather not get into command line headache.

Comment: did u ask your dbas to snap a dev clone?

Comment: Did anyone notice that if "Oracle" and "easy GUI tools" end up in one sentence, this sentence is always a question?

Comment: @Olaf thats probably because most people don't want to understand whats actually required, they're just looking for the easy button.  Same could be said for a lot of technologies. (no offense anon, just a general observation).

Comment: @tbone: This is an excellent point! I also think that Oracle's UI tools are harder to use/worse implemented than they should be.

Comment: What do you mean by download?  To your laptop?  Any idea how big the database could be... plus there are security issues if you have a copy of a database local to a PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use expdp and impdp, sorry. You may be able to find a GUI tool that runs impdp like TOAD, but in the end, it'll end up executing expdp/impdp.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way than the command line..sorry, oracle was build to get your hand dirty on thing unlike other small database.

Comment: Looks like a comment to me. Maybe it's on the topic, but... does it help at all?